Troubleshooting NG0203 Error: Issues with Angular Library and HttpClient Injection in Production Build
I wasn't able to solve it. I'm counting on your help.
I have an Angular application and a library.
In the library, I have a service where I inject HttpClient. I set HttpClient as a provider in the application. When I run the application using ng serve, everything works fine. However, when I create a build (ng build) and launch the application, I get error NG0203.
I've attached a link to the repository with this issue.
To run it:

Build the library (libs directory) - ng build
Launch the application (app1 directory) - ng serve
Create a production build (app1 directory) - ng build
Launch the build using, for example, a live server

Link to the repository:
https://github.com/tjaworski997/angular-library-inject-build-problem
I look forward to your help.

paths in tsconfig.json: "@angular/": ["./node_modules/@angular/"]
"preserveSymlinks": true in angular.json


After many attempts, I found the issue. The problem lies in the configuration of angular.json.
"@angular-devkit/build-angular:application" - does not work
"@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" - works correctly
Note: Changing this requires slight modifications to other parameters.|
From what I’ve read, using the browser builder means losing the ability to use SSR and Prerender. For now, I don’t need these features.
I’m leaving this note here in case someone else struggles with the same issue.
If anyone manages to find a solution for "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application", I’d appreciate the info.
